# Low jitter clock multiplier

Tags: clock, pll, jitter

I am using a 2-channel arbitrary waveform generator to generate two 40 MHz signals. The AWG also has a trigger signal output: short (~20 ns) pulses of ~2.5 V. The AWG has a negligible jitter of about 1 ps. All signals are single-ended 50 ohm.

I am looking for a method to generate a low jitter (< 25 ps rms) 80 MHz signal from the 40 MHz trigger output of the AWG. Preferably, this is a 'turn-key' solution I can buy off the shelf. I am not able to find / determine what I need.

1. I have looked into synchronising two AWG's by synchronising their 10 MHz reference clock, but I am not able to reach the required jitter specification. I have not been able to find a benchtop test equipment that would be capable of generating the 80 MHz signal, but perhaps I don't know the name of such an instrument.
2. I have found 'jitter cleaners' or 'jitter attenuators' IC's from multiple vendors (e.g. Skyworks, Silicon Labs, Texas Instruments, Analog Devices). Evaluation boards are available but it's difficult to compare the different solutions. These seem to be able to do what I need, although it is less 'plug and play'. I would welcome any recommendation on how to make a selection.
3. A last resort would be to spin-up a board myself, but I would prefer to stay away from this if possible. Similar to #2 I would need to select an IC for this. Any tips would be welcome.

Edit: added jitter spec of AWG.
Edit 2: added clarification on jitter signal and question

Comment: what's the jitter of the clock you want to generate this from? That would be important to know, because it makes a difference whether you can just more or less instantly multiply a frequency, or whether you need stable adjustable oscillator that you can *slowly* train to be twice the input frequency, while averaging out the jitter.

Comment: The AWG has a negligible jitter of about 1 ps

Comment: @Andrew what is your question?

Comment: thanks! is that trigger output short pulses, a square wave or even a sine?

Comment: Do you need low jitter on both edges of the 80mhz signal, or just one edge?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I am looking for a turn-key device I can buy that is able to generate a 80 MHz clock from the 40 MHz trigger signal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The trigger output are short (~20 ns) pulses of ~2.5 V amplitude

Comment: @colintd Ideally the jitter is low on both edges, but this could be a compromise

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the two 40MHz signals, in particular modulation and phase relationship? If they are in quadrature, clock recovery and XOR will give you 8pMHz

Comment: @colintd the two signals are related to the (physics) experiment. Typically, but not guaranteed, they are 10 Vpp and each other's inverse, with varying phase and duty cycle